# What is the best key for a React element in a list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Imagine I have this array of objects

```
fullList = [
  {label: "item A", id="itemA", someBool: true}, 
  {label: "item B", id="itemB", someBool: true}, 
  {label: "item C", id="itemC", someBool: true}, 
  {label: "item D", id="itemD", someBool: false}, 
  {label: "item E", id="itemE", someBool: false},
];
```

But I'm not rendering the full list on the screen. I'm filtering it based on some filter values and I'm rendering a filtered list.

The user interacts with the filters and will see different filtered lists based on what he/she choses as selected filters.

Then I have **two options for the keys:**

```
const filteredList = fullList.filter((item) => item.someBool === true);

const filteredListItems = filteredList.map((item,index) => 
  <Item_UI_Component
    key={item.id}          // OPTION #1 - THIS IS ONLY POSSIBLE IF THE FULL LIST CONTAINS id's
    key={index}            // OPTION #2 - THIS IS ALWAYS POSSIBLE
    ...SOME OTHER PROPS
  />
);
```

**QUESTION**

What is the practical difference between the two approachs? Do I gain or lose something with either one of them? Does React optimize something if I give the elements a UNIVERSALLY unique key as in OPTION #1? Or will it behave the same in both situations?

**OPTION #1:**

- The key is a unique ID no matter what
- The same element always get the same ID on every render

**Option #2:**

- The key is always unique on the `filteredList`, but the same element may be re-rendered with a different key than the one from the previous render.

---

**Note:** If you don't set any key, you'll get the warning:

> **Warning:** Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys for more information.

Comment: Just what the document says. Whatever value which is the most unique and consistent should be your key prop.

Comment: It is definitely NOT recommended to use the index, SPECIFICALLY for use cases like yours, where the list may change depending on filters. You want to use the id if that's available,

Comment: Nothing special. Warning is not a matter.

Comment: @TKoL not available, but I can loop and create one when I get the data.

Comment: The reason is because if your filter changes, and the item that is now at index 2 is not the same as the item that used to be at index 2, there's a very real risk that React will get confused and rather than rendering a new Component there, it will just change the props it sends the component -- and it may not visually update at all depending on how you've coded it

Comment: Why not have a composite key? `key={ \`${item.id}_${index}\` }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

> When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort. We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.

As I said in my comment:

The reason is because if your filter changes, and the item that is now at index 2 is not the same as the item that used to be at index 2, there's a very real risk that React will get confused and rather than rendering a new Component there, it will just change the props it sends the component -- and it may not visually update at all depending on how you've coded it.

I've definitely had issues by using index as key before personally

Comment: One thing some people may not know about keys that might also help you, OP: if you want to force a component to re-render from scratch, it's sometimes a great option to use a key. This is particularly true for stateful components

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten about this. It's been a while since I've coded a filter page. But for elements that don't change, you still use the `index` right? It's impractical to have unique string id's for everything. Example: for the filter options (always rendered in the same order): `filterOptions = ["optionA", "optionB", "optionC"]` you could go : `const filterItems = filterOptions.map((item,index) => <Filter_Item_UI key={index}/>);` Or would you use the filter value / label as a key to avoid index at all costs? In this case there's no difference, right?

Comment: @cbdeveloper if the array you're rendering will not change order or elements ever, and cannot be updated, then i don't think there's a huge risk of using the index. Also, I think there's low risk of using index as key for fully functional components

Answer (score 4):

If your data has a natural unique id, you should use it as key.

If your data don't have a natural id, you can use the index as key if all the following conditions are met:

1. the list and items are static – they are not computed and do not change
2. the items in the list have no ids
3. the list is never reordered or filtered.

[Source](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

If your data don't have a natural id, and you need to change your list, you can add a new ID property to your model or hash some parts of the content to generate a key. The key only has to be unique among its siblings, not globally unique.

[Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys)