# Does using `index` as the key in multiple `.map( element, index)` affect React's reactivity?

Tags: reactjs

If you have:

```
<div>
    { books.map( ( book, index ) => (
        <div key={ index }>
            { book.label }
        </div>
    ) ) }
    { movies.map( ( movie, index ) => (
        <div key={ index }>
            { movie.label }
        </div>
    ) ) }

</div>
```

As the `index` would be 0, 1, 2, etc. That means there will be divs with the "same" key value.

Does the index being inside a `.map()` make it unique or should each key be set like this to be unique in the entire app: `<div key={ 'book-' + index }>` and `<div key={ 'movie-' + index }>`?

Comment: Have you read the docs about keys? https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: using index as key for items in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59517962/react-using-index-as-key-for-items-in-the-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key being unique to a particular returned `.map` is enough. Your current code is fine - *in that sense*.

But it would be better not to use the index as the key, in general - if the `books` or `movies` arrays ever have items removed or shifted around, the index will not be reliable as a key, because the same "movie" would then have a different index. Better to pick something unique from those objects - if no two movies will have the same `movie.label`, for example, that could be a good choice for a key. (or if you have anything like a unique `.movieId` property, that'd work too)