# React Redux Useselector Hook Not re-render after store state update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I want to remove an item from an array in redux store, which served as a history array. But the state change does not always trigger re-render. I have to click 4 times delete button, or change tab in order to see state change to trigger re-render.

I have tried the following:

- using shallowEqual as comparison function
- using `Object.assign` for a new array object, to trigger state change

But, still no luck. Anyone please guide me on this. My codes are below:

Action:

```
export function removeHistoryPlaces(index) {
  return { 
    type: type.REMOVE_HISTORY_PLACES,
    payload: index,
  }
}
```

store configure

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/index.js";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import rootSaga from "./sagas/index";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

// TO TEST WITH DEV TOOL
// const store = compose(
//   applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
//   window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension(),
// )(createStore)(rootReducer);

const store = createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

reducer

```
const initialState = {
  historyPlaces: [],
}

export default function historyPlaces(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
      case type.REMOVE_HISTORY_PLACES:
        // const newList = Object.assign([],[...state.historyPlaces].filter((place,index)=>index != action.payload))
        // const isSame = newList === state.historyPlaces
        // console.log("new place list " , newList)
        return {
          ...state,
          historyPlaces: state.historyPlaces.filter((place,index)=>index != action.payload),
        }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

HistoryList component where user can view, click and delete history

```
import Chip from "@mui/material/Chip";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { removeHistoryPlaces } from "../redux/actions/historyPlaces";

export default function HistoryList({ data, onItemClick }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const maxDisplay = 5;

  const handleDelete = (index) => {
    dispatch(removeHistoryPlaces(index));
  };

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={1}>
      {data.slice(0, maxDisplay).map((item, index) => (
        <Chip
        style={{maxWidth:'200px'}}
          key={new Date().getTime()}
          label={item.description}
          onClick={()=>onItemClick(item)}
          onDelete={()=>handleDelete(index)}
        />
      ))}
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Home page where HistoryList component is used

```
import HistoryList from "../components/HistoryList";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch, shallowEqual } from 'react-redux';

const libraries = ['places'];
export default function Home() {
  const [currentFocusLocation,setCurrentFocusLocation] = useState('')
  const places = useSelector(state => state.historyPlaces.historyPlaces,shallowEqual);
  const onItemClick = (item) =>{
     ...
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('places update detected')
    setCurrentFocusLocation(...)
  },[places])

  if (!isLoaded) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  return (
    <>
      <div className="home-container">
        <HistoryList data={places} onItemClick={onItemClick}/>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

For complete codes, can check this [github link](https://github.com/zeehoe/my-google-map-react)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: using index as key for items in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59517962/react-using-index-as-key-for-items-in-the-list)

Comment: This is not a redux problem.  Do not use `index` as a `key`.  The purpose of the `key` is to be able to use that information if something has changed and `index` doesn't change with the data until you have a list that's shorter than the thing you're trying to delete.

Comment: @possum Thanks for the help. However, unique id still not solve the issue. I still need to perform 4 clicks in order to let re-render to take action. Do you still have any clue on my mistakes? Please help.