# Custom function I made that returns <span> elements is getting "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create a function that takes an array of words such as:

```js
const words = ['hello', 'my', 'name']
```

and returns them in the form:

```html
<>
<span>hello</span> // <span>my</span> // <span>name</span>
</>
```

This is the react component I created to do this:

```js
function StyleWords({words, ...props}){
    return(
        words.map((word, index, words) => {
            if(index != words.length-1){
                return <><span key={word} className='highlight'>{word}</span> // </>
            }
            else{
                return <span key={word} className='highlight'>{word}</span>
            } 
        })
    )
}
```

and then call it like so:

```js
<div><StyledWords words={['hello', 'my', 'name']} /></div>
```

Now this does work but I get the warning about keys. So my thinking is that either I have done this inappropriately or that I have missed something out with the keys. Any help?

Comment: key needs to be set on the top level node, returned from map. You are returning `<>...</>` which is also a node. Replace it with <React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment> and add a key to it, not to the nested span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the `key` to the component which is the root of the item in the list.

```js
function StyleWords({words, ...props}){
    return(
        words.map((word, index, words) => {
            if(index != words.length-1){
                return <React.Fragment key={word}>
                  <span className='highlight'>{word}</span> // 
                </React.Fragment>
            }
            else{
                return <span key={word} className='highlight'>{word}</span>
            } 
        })
    )
}
```

As Lokesh suggested, you should use a unique value as `key` for the items instead of using `word` if it is not guaranteed that it will be unique.

Comment: With this solution, make sure you do not have repeated words in the array. 

If there is a possibility of having repeated words then index can also be used as a value to key attribute. It is a good fit for list which are static is nature like no delete/update operations are getting performed on that list. So, do consider reading out this post answers before making that decision.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59517962/react-using-index-as-key-for-items-in-the-list

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. Just not sure if this is a good method of producing this component in the first place

Comment: @LokeshYadav Great point. Updated.

Comment: @LokeshYadav Yes, I was intitially using index. Should switch back.